# FATAL: Listen error: unable to monitor directories for changes

Tags: css, sass, compass

I am trying to watch a sass directory .I created sass project using the following command on my ubuntu 16.4 system

```
 compass create sass
```

And got the result

```
directory sass/  directory sass/sass/  directory sass/stylesheets/     create sass/config.rb     create sass/sass/screen.scss     create sass/sass/print.scss     create sass/sass/ie.scss 
        write sass/stylesheets/ie.css
        write sass/stylesheets/print.css
        write sass/stylesheets/screen.css

    ********************************************************************* Congratulations! Your compass project has been created.

    You may now add and edit sass stylesheets in the sass subdirectory of your project.

    Sass files beginning with an underscore are called partials and won't be compiled to CSS, but they can be imported into other sass stylesheets.

    You can configure your project by editing the config.rb configuration file.

    You must compile your sass stylesheets into CSS when they change. This can be done in one of the following ways:
      1. To compile on demand:
         compass compile [path/to/project]
      2. To monitor your project for changes and automatically recompile:
         compass watch [path/to/project]

    More Resources:   * Website: http://compass-style.org/   * Sass: http://sass-lang.com   * Community: http://groups.google.com/group/compass-users/


    To import your new stylesheets add the following lines of HTML (or equivalent) to your webpage: <head>   <link href="/stylesheets/screen.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />   <link href="/stylesheets/print.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />   <!--[if IE]>
          <link href="/stylesheets/ie.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />   <![endif]--> </head>
```

And i try to watch this using `compass watch` results an error as shown bellow

> > > > Compass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to Stop. FATAL: Listen error: unable to monitor directories for changes. Visit
> > > >         https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers
> > > >         for info on how to fix this.
> > > >         bharathi@bharathi-H81M-S:~/share/springwisev2/wp-content/themes/Springwise
> > > >         2016/library/sass$ compass watch

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just try to execute this from your console:

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

Hope this will work for you
.

References: [click_here](https://prashantrorblog.wordpress.com/2016/05/28/fatal-listen-error-unable-to-monitor-directories-for-changes/)